# How to detect remote user has connection issue after join the audio/video call?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

After joined channel, remote user may have connection issue. Which method can the local user detect the remote user has been disconnect and waiting for rejoin channel?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about flutter client, from example of AgoraIO, you can do this in event handler. see code snippet and full code below

If I do not understand your question clear, please post your code.

full code 
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/blob/master/lib/src/pages/call.dart

code snippet

```
/// Add agora event handlers
  void _addAgoraEventHandlers() {
    AgoraRtcEngine.onError = (int code) {
      setState(() {
        String info = 'onError: ' + code.toString();
        _infoStrings.add(info);
      });
    };

    AgoraRtcEngine.onJoinChannelSuccess =
        (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        String info = 'onJoinChannel: ' + channel + ', uid: ' + uid.toString();
        _infoStrings.add(info);
      });
    };

    AgoraRtcEngine.onLeaveChannel = () {
      setState(() {
        _infoStrings.add('onLeaveChannel');
      });
    };

    AgoraRtcEngine.onUserJoined = (int uid, int elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        String info = 'userJoined: ' + uid.toString();
        _infoStrings.add(info);
        _addRenderView(uid, (viewId) {
          AgoraRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(viewId, VideoRenderMode.Hidden, uid);
        });
      });
    };

    AgoraRtcEngine.onUserOffline = (int uid, int reason) {
      setState(() {
        String info = 'userOffline: ' + uid.toString();
        _infoStrings.add(info);
        _removeRenderView(uid);
      });
    };

    AgoraRtcEngine.onFirstRemoteVideoFrame =
        (int uid, int width, int height, int elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        String info = 'firstRemoteVideo: ' +
            uid.toString() +
            ' ' +
            width.toString() +
            'x' +
            height.toString();
        _infoStrings.add(info);
      });
    };
  }
```